# Do hamiltonian paths exist on n-valent, simple, connected, planar graphs, where n>2?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I don't know to much about graph theory, so was wondering about the posted question. If it is too much perhaps you may know the answer if n is even? Any help is appreciated. Also, this is my first time posting here so if I've done something that is not proper etiquette, please tell me.

Comment: By "$n$-valent" you mean every vertex has degree $n$ (also known as "$n$-regular")?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for the confusion. Also I believe the answer is yes answer (just in case someone wants to know in the future). I've also found out that planar n-regular graphs do not exist for n>5, this was a bit disappointing :(